# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_ref.state)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo, react-navigation, redux-saga

I am trying to configure React Native with Redux, Saga, and React Navigation.

So sorry I had to create a gist as the code formatting didn't allow me to paste all code here.

[My Code Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/sahilpaudel/3ee091d6dd1e922a40e4fcf71d15b73c)

I am getting

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating '_ref.state) 
>   showReducers.js:13:15

I am using `expo-client` to React Native app development and using Redux, Redux-Saga and Redux-Persist for store persistence.

I can't move ahead

Comment: Hi Sahil. If you have too much code to paste, please reduce it to a [mcve]. This is much more likely to get you good answers as people can easily see what the problem  is and don't have to dig through tons of unrelated code. Also, links tend to break, making your question useless for others with the same problem. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `initialState` isn't defined in `showReducer.js`, thus the default value of `state` is set to `undefined` here:

> `export default ({ state = initalState, action })...`

So when you use the spread operator:

```
return {
     ...state,
     isCreateScrapbookModal: true
}
```

You are trying to evaluate an object `state`, but `state` is actually `undefined`, so you get that error.